# convert a double with a comma to a variable with a point to use in sql statement

Tags: c#

I use my double in a select statement:

code:

```
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT min(Score) FROM "+ table +" WHERE [" + sportEvent + "] < (@result);", connect);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result", result);
```

everything works fine if double result is an integer but not if result is a comma number (example 11,34) --> it should be 11.34 to work (point instead of comma)

How can I change a double 11,34 into 11.34 ?

Comment: What is the datatype of the variable `result` added as parameter value?

Comment: the datatype of result is double

Comment: A `double` itself doesn't have a `.` or `,` - it's just a number. If `result` is a `double` variable, then your problem is *filling* that variable, presumably with a `double.TryParse` or `Convert.ToDouble`. Can you show us *that* code?

Comment: Please share your code and tell me if you are using localization in your project??

Comment: What errors do you get when `result` is `11.34`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your code sets a string parameter as a constraint for a DB value of numeric type, letting the database do the conversion. This is not a good idea, because it takes control away from your program: should DBA decide to reconfigure your backend database to "understand" commas instead of dots, your program will stop working!

Currently, your `double` is in a locale-specific format. You need to parse it using the locale-specific format provider, and then set the value that you get back from the parser as the parameter of your SQL query. Assuming that the current culture is one that is using commas as decimal separator, you can do this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@result"
,   double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: I got an error `No overload for method 'toString' takes 1 arguments`

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the variable into string:

```
result.ToString().Replace(',','.');
```

This will replace the comma with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

If result is Double then:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.Float).Value = result
```